# "winload.efi" missing or contains errors? New windows install on SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, clone, nvme, bcdboot

Hi I've just installed a new SSD. I then made a windows boot usb from the media creation tool via Microsoft. I then installed Windows 10 to the ssd. Once I tried booting to the SSD I got the error

```
The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors
File: \Windows\system32\winload.efi
Error code: 0xc000000e
```

The ssd is an NVME M.2 drive which I'm connecting via a pcie adapter to my Asus z77a-g43 motherboard. The other windows drive has no problem booting. I've tried cloning that drive with a tool called macrium to no avail. I've also tried using rufus and a windows ISO rather than using the media creation tool to make my own bootable usb. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

When I run software repair, it gives me no solutions. I've tried using the `bcdboot` commands but have had no luck - though I'd be open to trying them if someone thinks those are the trick.

I have no problem mounting the drive and copying files to it via windows on my original drive. It just seems that this one file won't copy over or is corrupted. I understand it has to do with the bootloader.

Comment: I would disconnect your existing drive then reinstall Windows while in UEFI mode.  This should be the default since you have a NVMe driver.  Without knowing the specifics of the adapter I cannot determine if it’s designed to be bootable

Comment: Am I allowed to link to amazon to show it? [This is it](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07VYWR91T/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: And [this is the drive](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07K1J3C23/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: After removing my SATA SSD, I reinstalled Windows on my nvme drive but still no luck.

Comment: The system just hangs at the motherboard splash screen now.